# Pycharm running pytest parametrized tests not showing all of the tests, just the one running

Tags: pycharm, pytest

We have a suite of pytest unit tests using a parametrized system with pytest_generate_tests. On my copy of pycharm, when I run the test suite, I see output like this:

[image: Good pycharm]

I can scroll through and examine the output and results of each test individually.

On my coworkers pycharm the output is like this:

[image: bad pycharm]

It only shows the currently running test.

I'll note I'm running Pycharm Pro and my coworker whose Pycharm is of concern is Community.

What setting controls this? I'm having a lot of trouble googling this.

Answer (score 0):

I love how writing a question helps me just answer it myself.

The answer is the little checkmark and universal no sign. Checkmark means show passed, universal no means show ignored.